# Industry standard way of testing websites on various devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am essentially looking for the BrowserLab of Devices. What would the normal process be for a big design agency to ensure that their websites look the same across a wide array of the standard devices? The Nexus, iPad 1,2 and 3, so on and so forth.

Edit: I was hoping for answers that didnt involve breaking the bank and buying every device under the sun.

Comment: read that : http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-alternatives-to-Device-Anywhere-for-mobile-device-testing

Comment: ... also, given that your site may be browsed by devices covering a really broad range of screen sizes and resolutions, websites are definitely not going to "look the same."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from testing on the physical devices, you could also test them using their respective SDKs and emulators, such as the [Android Developer Tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/index.html). Even if you're not using it to develop native apps, you could still create Android Virtual Machines (AVDs) and load the browser in them to see what it'd look like on that device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) to test the websites by creating test cases in Ruby. It features a standard test case:

1. Describe behaviour in plain text
2. Write a step definition in Ruby
3. Run and watch it fail
4. Write code to make the step pass
5. Run again and see the step pass
6. Repeat 2-5 until green like a cuke
7. Repeat 1-6 until the money runs out

From their website:

> Cucumber lets software development teams describe how software should behave in plain text. The text is written in a business-readable domain-specific language and serves as documentation, automated tests and development-aid - all rolled into one format

Also, there are online tools like:

- [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)
- [Test on Real Mobile Devices without Breaking the Bank](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/test-on-real-mobile-devices-without-breaking-the-bank/)